# How can I assign a hexadecimal number to another number?

Tags: javascript

How can I assign the below code to a number?

```
Integer.toHexString( myHexValue );
```

Comment: Is myHexValue not a number already?

Answer (score 5):

The second optional argument to parseInt is the radix.

```
parseInt("0xff", 16);
// yields 255
```

Comment: +1 — Also, the "0x" is optional when specifying the radix, so `x == parseInt(Integer.toHexString(x), 16)`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it back to an integer...

```
var s = "FFFFFF";
var n = parseInt("0x"+ s);
```

Comment: It's actually just a coincidence that "0xff" parses to 255 without a radix, because most JS implementations read the "0x" and proceed to parse the rest as hex.  Unfortunately the output of most int->hex procedures omits the "0x" and would not work in this case.

Comment: P.S.  Sorry, I see that you're doing parseInt("0x" + s), but still I'd say that's less than optimal when you have other options.

Comment: I really don't see how what I'm doing is different from what you're doing.  He's assigning the hex value to a string variable, which I'm doing directly whereas in his example he's using Integer.toHexString, and then I'm doing the exact same thing you are, but not specifying the radix, which is optional anyhow.  So I'm not following your point...

Comment: I think I confused the issue by adding  "0x" in my original example.  The original question is posed in terms of a string generated by Java's Integer::toHexString, which returns a plain hex string without the "0x".

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the hex value as a "Number". For example:

```
foo = Number(0xDEADBEEF)
```

Hope this helps.